# Is $x^{q^n-1}-1$ where $q$ is a power of a prime $p$ irreducible over $F_{q^n}$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Here the tower of extension is $\Bbb F_p\subset \Bbb F_q\subset E$ where $E$ is an  extension of degree $n$ over $\Bbb F_q$ and $q=p^r$ for some natural number $r$. I wonder if it is the fact that $x^{q^n-1}-1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_q$. If it is, could someone please give a proof? Or else if it is not irreducible, could someone give some explaination?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $1$ is a root of your polynomial, so no.

Comment: @carmichael561 Get it, thanks!

Comment: $$x^{q^n-1}-1 = (x-1)\sum_{k= 0}^{q^n-2} x^k$$

Comment: Every non-zero element of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ is a zero of your polynomial by Lagrange's theorem from elementary group theory. Therefore $x^{q^n-1}-1$ is the product of their minimal polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_q$. In other words, all the irreducible polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $d\mid n$ are its factors (with the exception of $p(x)=x$ because that is the minimal polynomial of $0$).